# Why there are no colors in the code text in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[Code Text Colorless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hFPc.png)

When I code in **Visual Studio**, it doesn't show any colours in the code text. It shows blue and green colours only for the **class** and **comments** texts. Also, VS doesn't suggest me anything when I code. Apart from this, everything things run fine and if there are any errors it shows up in the problem section.

I am doing **flutter**/ **dart**

*I would really appreciate it if anyone helps me sort it out.*

*Thank you :)*

Comment: Did you install any plugin for Flutter in vscode?

Comment: Did you install Dart and Flutter Visual Studio code extensions?

Comment: is it possible to share some parts of code pictures?. and if you run the code do you have any error on the console

Comment: @YunusKocatas No, I don't face errors in the console, unless I make any code errors, other than that, everything runs smoothly. You can check out the screenshot from this link: https://imgur.com/a/tBkSAka

Comment: @zabaykal Yes, I did that, and there are still no colours in the snippets or widgets.

Comment: @LuisGurmendez Yes, I did that.

Comment: did you tried the cons value?

Comment: @YunusKocatas Where can I get this Cons Value?

Comment: i mean const value in your code comes after padding !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was fixed, once I updated VS code and restarted it. The text colour for every widget and class was back after that.

Answer (score 52):

I think the issue is likely the VS Code theme you're using. **Dark (Visual Studio)** only shows limited colours - try changing it to **Dark+** and you should see more colours.

**Dark**

[image: Dark theme]

**Dark+**

[image: Dark+ theme]

---

To Change This Settings;

Setting Icon **>** Color Theme **>** Select **Dark+** Configuration;

[image: Change Theme Settings]

[image: Dark+ Configuration]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried that and did not work. But anyway this issue got fixed when I uploaded the VS code and restarted it. :)

Comment: Save my day thanks DUDEE!!!

Answer (score 19):

Happened to me today, hope it helps someone: in my case it was just a broken extension `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` from Microsoft. After uninstalling, everything went back to normal.

Comment: Uninstalling JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly (v5.0.20221117) restored the syntax highlighting colors. Reinstalling it caused JavaScript and TypeScript to go white (except for parentheses and brackets). I'm leaving this extension uninstalled, it just replaces VS Code's built-in TypeScript.

Comment: In my case the JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension had a "Restart Required" button. Clicking this solved my issue. No need to uninstall it. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I am not using VS but you might try to add Flutter and Dart extension from marketplace.

Comment: I have already installed all the plugins like flutter and dart. Everything works fine except there are no colours or code suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. In VS Code, open the Color Theme picker with File > Preferences > Color Theme. (Code > Preferences > Color Theme on macOS).
2. You can also use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K Ctrl+T to display the picker.
3. Use the cursor keys to preview the colors of the theme.
4. Select the theme you want and press Enter.

Comment: I don't have any issue with the theme, All of the codes I have written are in white. I need colours in the codes for a better understanding.

Comment: If you change the theme it will automatically change the code color. Different themes have different code colors.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was checking if I had any deprecated or problems with an extension. Go to extensions in vs code (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>) check if any of your installed extensions has a problem; a warning yellow sign should appear below if your extension is deprecated or has any other problem. Fix the faulty extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin developed by OmniSharp (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) is being installed to develop in C# language. Here is the C# plugin; Occasionally, there may be annoying situations that I think are caused by the caching design of the plugin. (For example; the situation that occurs after a class is moved from one place to another, the class cannot be defined where it is used, or intellisense does not work).
To solve this, check if there is Omnisharp with Ctrl+Shift+P and download it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try installing "Flutter Widget Snippets" for already written code snippets from VS code Extensions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am using this extension, Still figuring out, how can I fix this.